# Issue with dynamic picklist in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, picklist

I have a dynamic picklist in a lightning component :

```
<lightning:select name="selectField" label="Champ" required="true" aura:id="selectField">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.fields}" var="field">
                    <option text="{!field.value}" value="{!field.key}"/>
                </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

The options are displayed correctly, but when I click an option to select it, it does not select it.

I see that there is an attribute `value` available for the tag `lightning:select` but I don't know what to put inside it, and there is an attribute `selected` for the tag `option` but I don't know which value to put in it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the "Selected" attribute, on the Option element Ex:

```
<option text="{!field.label}" value="{!field.value}" selected="{!field.selected}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me - I have an attribute for the selected value, and a changehandler to handle changes, which lets you access the selected value:

```
 <aura:attribute name="selectedValue" type="String"/>
 <aura:attribute name="accountrtvalues" type="List"/>

 <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.selectedValue}" action="
{!c.handleChange}"/>

 <lightning:select name="mySelect" label="Select a Record Type:" aura:id="mySelect" value="{!v.selectedValue}">
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.accountrtvalues}" var="item">
 <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}" selected="{!item.selected}"/>
 </aura:iteration>
 </lightning:select>
```

Then in controller:

```
 handleChange: function (component, event, helper) {
        //Do something with the change handler
        console.log(event.getParam('value') )
 },
```

Comment: the op is missing the selected attribute